# Html attribute camel-case with vue directive

Tags: html, vue.js, razor, vuejs3, vue-directives

I am working on a MVC project with Vue.js(Vue3) front-end.
For some reason when I am trying to use any directive that contains camel-case arguments, like in the example below, they are automatically turned to all lower-case, rendering my directive completely ineffective.

```
<label for="Name" class="required" v-init:camelCaseAttribute="'variableValue"> labelValue </label>
```

This also happens when I define said atributes with the use of a dictionary:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Registration.Section03.Address.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "v-init:camelCaseAttribute", "'variableValue'" } })
```

I know this is a HTML thing, but are there any known work-arounds for this?

Should have provided more context to the question:

```
   const myComponent = { // my component
    data: function () {
        return {
            camelCaseProperty: '' // property I am trying to initialise with some value
        }
    },
    directives: {
        init: { // custom init directive
            mounted(el, binding, vnode) {
                console.log(binding.arg)
                binding.instance[binding.arg] = binding.value;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

"init" is indeed not a built in Vue directive, so as I am trying to migrate the project from angularjs, which has an init directive, I tried to come up with something that offers a similar functionality to some extent, as seen in the snippet.
Writing the directive argument in kebab-case (v-init:camel-case-property="something") has no effect, as logging the binding.arg that actually reaches the directive is still in kebab-case.

Comment: I take it you're not using Single File Components? In my experience, snake-cased attributes are analogous to camelCased attributes when used in vue SFC templates, so you could try v-init:camel-case-attribute, but I'm not sure if that works outside of vue's SFC compiler.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am not using SFC. Vue instance is defined in JS file and then I am mounting it in Razor view

Comment: It'd help if you showed what you tried with some more code. `v-directive:your-argument-here="propValue"` should work for yourArgumentHere, if yourArgumentHere and propValue are defined in the setup of the component you're rendering the label with. `v-init` isn't a directive that's included in Vue3, so is that a pseudocode example or from a library? If you're simply trying to pass a prop, you could use v-bind (eventually with `.camel` modifier, as explained here: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-bind).

Comment: I have just updated my question. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

This can happen; it is therefore recommended in to use kebab-case for all html attributes in Vue, including props.

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase

[source](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-casing-camelcase-vs-kebab-case)

Comment: _That means when you're using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:_   [source](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-casing-camelcase-vs-kebab-case).                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                   I have tried to use hyphen in html attribute name but it's still converting to lowercase

Comment: Use lowercase. Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be. Always use lowercase in HTML; just in case ;)